# c++ i/o locks an empty file

Tags: c++, io, ifstream

I have create a function to return the size of a file

```
int thFileClass::getFileSize (){
streampos begin,end;
ifstream myfile (m_szFile,std::ios::binary);
if (myfile.peek() != std::ifstream::traits_type::eof()){
    if (myfile.is_open()){
        begin = myfile.tellg();
        myfile.seekg (0, myfile.end);
        end = myfile.tellg();
        myfile.close();
        cout << "size is: " << (end-begin) << " bytes.\n";
        return end-begin;
    } 
} else {
    myfile.close();
}
return 0;
}
```

But if the file is empty it locks it. So the next time I got to open the file for read/write it won't open 
    MyFile.is_open()==false;

Any ideas why this is or how i could stop the file from locking?

P.S. myfile.close(); is always called in the above function.

**UPDATE**

Even if my code is a simple as opening and closing the file it gets locked.

```
ifstream myfile (m_szFile,std::ios::binary);
myfile.close();
```

Comment: Please leave a comment if you downvote

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
int getFileSize() {
        streampos begin, end;
        ifstream myfile("1.txt");
        if (myfile.peek() != std::ifstream::traits_type::eof()) {
            if (myfile.is_open()) {
                begin = myfile.tellg();
                myfile.seekg(0, myfile.end);
                end = myfile.tellg();
                myfile.close();
                cout << "size is: " << (end - begin) << " bytes.\n";
            }
        }
        myfile.close();
        return end - begin;
    }
```

Comment: Even if I do ifstream myfile (m_szFile,std::ios::binary);
 myfile.close(); the file gets locked

Comment: All works. When your file locked? In your code if myfile.peek() != std::ifstream::traits_type::eof() is true then you didn`t close file